# "The statement did not return a result set" on Create table (JDBC)

Tags: jdbc, resultset, create-table

I try to add a new table in my SQL Server database using Java, so I create the following code:

```
public void createTable(String _createTableQuery, String _tableName) throws SQLException {
        
        try {
            Connection conn;    
            Statement statement = null;
            
            statement = conn.createStatement();
                        
            statement.executeQuery(_createTableQuery);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in CREATE TABLE:");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

The value of _createTableQuery is:

```
CREATE TABLE TestCSV ([Wine] VARCHAR(100), [Alcohol] VARCHAR(100), [Malic.acid] VARCHAR(100), [Ash] VARCHAR(100), [Acl] VARCHAR(100), [Mg] VARCHAR(100), [Phenols] VARCHAR(100), [Flavanoids] VARCHAR(100), [Nonflavanoid.phenols] VARCHAR(100), [Proanth] VARCHAR(100), [Color.int] VARCHAR(100), [Hue] VARCHAR(100), [OD] VARCHAR(100), [Proline] VARCHAR(100));
```

When I execute the code I get the following error:

[com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1DSK.png)

After this error, If I check the table creation in SQL Server, I can see the new table under my database. So the query works but I get the error in any case.

I looked for this error in google and I found this is a problem when the query has not results, so I try to add "SET NOCOUNT ON" in the query:

```
CREATE TABLE TestCSV ([Wine] VARCHAR(100), [Alcohol] VARCHAR(100), [Malic.acid] VARCHAR(100), [Ash] VARCHAR(100), [Acl] VARCHAR(100), [Mg] VARCHAR(100), [Phenols] VARCHAR(100), [Flavanoids] VARCHAR(100), [Nonflavanoid.phenols] VARCHAR(100), [Proanth] VARCHAR(100), [Color.int] VARCHAR(100), [Hue] VARCHAR(100), [OD] VARCHAR(100), [Proline] VARCHAR(100)) SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

With NOCOUNT ON I get the same error.
I also try to define a new ResultSet in my Java code, but I get the same error again.

Comment: use `executeUpdate()` or `execute()` - `executeQuery()` is only for statements returning a result set

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I try with executeUpdate() but I get the same error. So I try with execute() and now it works fine. As I understand is because executeUpdate() is only for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE, not for CREATE TABLE statement. Is It correct?